# Generation of code for VB and debugging in C# Project

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-generation

In the C#-Project is generated an VB-file, after that the file is compiled in the separated thread and is maked useful work :). I would like not only generate this file but load this file to debugger and begin it to debug (if DEBUG is defined). Is it possible in C# project to debug VB file? I was found T4 Templates for the VB-file formatting, but I'm not sure, that these templates could me help to debug the file.

Comment: Visual studio will debug what ever assemblies are loaded into memory with PDBs. You'll need to load the VB assembly and PDB with [`AppDomain.Load Method (Byte[], Byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tc2453.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English obviously isn't your first language and I what you've said doesn't make much sense. But I think I get a rough idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

It is possible to run C# and VB.Net projects side by side in Visual Studio.

1. Open your C# solution
2. From the 'File' Menu select 'Add...' > 'Existing solution'
3. Select your VB solution
4. In the Solution Explorer pane, right click on whichever solution you want to be the startup solution and select 'Set as Startup Project'

You should now be able to put break points in either project and debug them easily.

Hope that helps!